# Don't want to centre the content on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

This my `UITableViewCell` without expanding . The contents on the `UITableView` are horizontally centered as the behavior of the table view .

[image]

this is my `UITableViewCell` with expansion . Here contents again get centered automatically . But I want the content at the same place as in first image . anyone have idea how can it be done ?

Comment: reset frame of label in case of expansion.

Comment: @rptwsthi:its not working .I have CGRect rect= cell.name.bounds; but I am getting x and y 0.

Comment: You cant change the frame of the cell label. For that you have to take UILabel.

Comment: Use custom label on your cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option you have here is to **create your own** tableViewCell since predefined cell styles don't allow customization.

You can either place in it a **custom label that allows top vertical alignment** like [SSLabel](http://sstoolk.it/documentation/Classes/SSLabel.html#//api/name/verticalTextAlignment) in the [SSToolkit](http://sstoolk.it/) or add a **normal UILabel** to the top and prevent it from resizing its height with the cell.